# how to get chat folders? - telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm trying to get the chat folders using `telethon`

I'm not sure what to do and there's nothing I found in the documentation. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folders are called Filters in the full api, you can get them with [GetDialogFilters](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/get_dialog_filters.html)

```
req = await client(functions.messages.GetDialogFiltersRequest())
```

The req will be of type [`DialogFilter`](https://tl.telethon.dev/types/dialog_filter.html) which can be either of:

- DialogFilterDefault:
  ignore it, it was added as premium feature to sort "All" tab
- DialogFilter:
  This is a Folder basically, it contains title, included chats, pinned, excluded, etc..

Get the existing fields at auto generated [TL site](https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/dialog_filter.html) or their info @[official TG site](https://core.telegram.org/constructor/dialogFilter)